# Generic Failure on Register-WmiEvent for Win32_Service

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, wmi

I'm trying to catch creation, deletion and modifications of services on my local machine.
In order to do that, I'm using the powershell command Register-WmiEvent with Win32_Service (in this specific code example it's creation):

$Query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WHITHIN 1 WHERE targetInstance ISA 'Win32_Service'"
$Identifier = "ServiceCreation"
Register-WmiEvent -Query $Query -SourceIdentifier $Identifier

It works for me with other Win32 classes, but for some reason for this class I get this Error Message:
Register-WmiEvent: Generic Failure

Things I've tried:

- Reset my computer.
- Wbemtest- ran the query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service" and get the same error message with this error code: 0x80041001.
- Deleted my profile folder.
- Ran with different admin user.
- Reset the WMI repository (salvagerepository and resetrepository) in an administrative command prompt.
- Reloaded performance counters with %WINDIR%\system32\lodctr /R (and for SysWow64) in an administrative command prompt.
- Looked in wbem log but didn't see anything looks connected.

It should be noted that the same script runs fine on the exact same computer.
Anything else I found online was this error occures when running the query remotely (but I'm running locally), or running on Windows XP or Windows Vista (but I'm running on Windows 10) or this is a powershell bug with no solution (but it's just a sucks answer).

Please help, what else can I try?
I've been searching everywhere on the Internet for three days.

Comment: "It should be noted that the same script runs fine on the exact same computer." - so the problem is fixed? Or does it only work _sometimes_?

Comment: It works fine on other computers, just not on mine- the one I tested it on (a lot of times)